# Integrate autoinstall config into Ubuntu server ISO

Tags: server, system-installation, 20.04, iso

I would like to automatically install Ubuntu Server 20.04 using autoinstall config file. However, official Ubuntu documentation describes two options. One is to serve this file over http. Other option is to create ISO from it and mount as another drive during the installation. It is described here:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart
I would like to put this file into Ubuntu Server installation ISO and then automatically use it during the installation without http server or another dedicated ISO. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I used Cubic and added user-data and meta-data files to /cdrom/preseed/ directory. Then in Boot tab I had to edit /isolinux/txt.cfg file to include autoinstall parameter and point to the proper directory.
Here, in bold is what I had to add:

append boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet **autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=/cdrom/preseed/** ---

Answer (score 0):

Somebody created a project to insert the autoinstall configuration into the iso.  I have not used it myself, but it could be a good starting point for you

https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-autoinstall-generator

Comment: Your solution is probably good. However, I came up with my own, which I also described here. Thanks.